# Различие в результатах работы javac и Eclipse Compiler for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

Столкнулся с интересным различием поведения компиляторов `javac` и `Eclipse Compiler for Java` помогите разобраться почему их поведение отличается и какое соответствует спецификации!

Есть класс (назовём его `Parent`) в котором объявлен второй внутренний класс(назовем его `InnerClass`), который является потомком класс Parent. У обоих классов есть методы с одинаковыми именами (в примере имя `methodA`) но разной сигнатурой.

Проблема в том, что компилятор `javac` не видит `private` методы внешнего родительского класса при вызове их из потомка если у потомка есть метод с таким же именем, но другой сигнатурой. При этом `Eclipse` все устраивает код компилируется и запускается. Поведение одинаково как для статических методов так и для методов экземпляров.

Была идея, что `Eclipse` видит этот метод из области видимости т.к. оба находятся в теле родительского класса, а не через наследование.
Но если убрать наследование между классами `Parent` и `InnerClass` то `methodA` становиться недоступен и с точки зрения `Eclipse` кроме того это противоречит [вот этому параграфу JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.7.1) которым судя по всему и руководствуется `javac`.

Методы экземпляров:

```
Eclipse:
public class Parent {
    private void methodB(){}
    private void methodA(String a) {}

    class InnerClass extends Parent {
        private void methodA(Integer a) {}
        void callPrivateSuper() {
            methodB();       //Eclipse BYTECODE -> INVOKESTATIC Parent.access$0 (LParent;)V
            methodA("");     //Eclipse BYTECODE -> INVOKESTATIC Parent.access$1 (LParent;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        }
    }
}

javac:
public class Parent {
    private void methodB(){}
    private void methodA(String a) {}

    class InnerClass extends Parent {
        private void methodA(Integer a) {}
        void callPrivateSuper() {
            methodB();
            methodA("");     //javac -> java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer
        }
    }
}
```

Статические методы:

```
Eclipse:
public class Parent {
    private static void methodB(){}
    private static void methodA(String a) {}

    class InnerClass extends Parent {
        private void methodA(Integer a) {}
        void callPrivateSuper() {
            methodB();     //Eclipse BYTECODE -> INVOKESTATIC Parent.access$0 ()V
            methodA("");   //Eclipse BYTECODE -> INVOKESTATIC Parent.access$1 (Ljava/lang/String;)V
        }
    }
}

javac:
public class Parent {
    private static void methodB(){}
    private static void methodA(String a) {}

    class InnerClass extends Parent {
        private void methodA(Integer a) {}
        void callPrivateSuper() {
            methodB();
            methodA("");   //javac ->  java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer
        }
    }
}
```

При этом если в родительском классе у метода `methodA` изменить модификатор доступа с `private` на любой другой то `javac` компилирует код и все работает согласно [JLS 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) и [JLS 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.7.1) теперь метод предка виден доступен через наследование.

```
public class Parent {
    void methodA(String a) {}

    class InnerClass extends Parent {
        private void methodA(Integer a) {}
        void callPrivateSuper() {
            methodA("");     //javac BYTECODE -> INVOKEVIRTUAL Parent$InnerClass.methodA (Ljava/lang/String;)V
                             //Eclipse BYTECODE -> INVOKEVIRTUAL Parent$InnerClass.methodA (Ljava/lang/String;)V
        }
    }
}
```

Почему того же что `Eclipse` не делает `javac` для `private` метода `methodA`?

Где в `JLS` и `JVMS` определено как должен вести себя компилятор в данном случае?

Правильно ли я понимаю что `private` методы не видны через наследования на [первом этапе определения выполняемого метода](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1), даже в том случае если эти методы доступны/видны по месту определения класса?

Comment: На ум приходит только версия `java`

Comment: Из коробки Eclipse не показывает некоторые предупреждения при программировании. Private поля и методы материнского класса не доступны дочерним классам. Ставьте Protected, если уж необходимо. Это модификатор распространяется на всё в основном классе и включая дочерние классы. На мой взгляд javac обоснованно вам это показывает. А вот Eclipse достаточно часто может компилировать нерабочий код. Всё зависит от того как вы его настроите.

Comment: Собственно [доказательство](http://joxi.ru/Q2KVaQwFLw9wlm) моего комментария. А [вот](http://joxi.ru/823bRoyf9D6Dvm) с protected модификатором.

Comment: @Rootware оформите пожалуйста как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Из "коробки" Eclipse не показывает некоторые предупреждения в коде при программировании. Поля и методы материнского класса с модификатором **private** не доступны дочерним классам. Используйте **protected**, если необходимо открыть доступ к полям/методам материнского класса для дочерних элементов. Этот модификатор предоставляет доступ к полю/методу всем в основном классе, включая дочерние классы.

На мой взгляд **javac** обоснованно вам это показывает. А вот Eclipse достаточно часто может компилировать "нерабочий" код. Всё зависит от того как вы его настроите.

Ели вам необходимо иметь более "жёсткие" правила анализа кода в Eclipse, то их можно изменить в: `Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings`.

Пример уведомлений Eclipse для **private** модификатора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример уведомлений Eclipse для **protected** модификатора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Давайте быть честными: дело вообще не в javac, а в настройках IDE. Которые вополне могут соответствовать нужному, при желании. Было бы это желание, немного почитать документацию, и нажать пару кнопочек.

Comment: @PinkTux я собственно это и писал.